# JAVA program Bouncing Ball, change the size (pulsating) with a boolean. How to do that?

Tags: java, dynamic, boolean, size

i have looked all over the internet and in my school books but I can't seem to slove my problem.

In my program "bouncing ball" (got the code from our teacher) i need to change the size of the ball from small to bigger and reverse. I understand that i need a boolean to do that and maybe alsow an if statment. This is what I have in the Ball class rigth now regarding the size change:

private boolean changeSize = true;

```
int maxSize = 10;
int minSize = 1;

public void changeSize(boolean size ){
    if(size == maxSize ){
        return minSize;
    }
    else return maxSize;

}


public void changeBallSize(int d, int f){
    diameter = d*f;
```

This is the whole code for the class Ball:

class Ball {

```
static int        defaultDiameter  = 10;
static Color      defaultColor     = Color.yellow;
static Rectangle  defaultBox       = new Rectangle(0,0,100,100);

// Position
private int x, y;

// Speen and angel 
private int dx, dy;

// Size 
private int diameter;

// Color 
private Color color;

// Bouncing area
private Rectangle box;

// New Ball
public Ball( int x0, int y0, int dx0, int dy0 ) {
    x = x0;
    y = y0;
    dx = dx0;
    dy = dy0;

    color = defaultColor;
    diameter = defaultDiameter;
}

// New color
public void setColor( Color c ) {
    color = c;
}


public void setBoundingBox( Rectangle r ) {
    box = r;
}

// ball  
public void paint( Graphics g ) {
    // Byt till bollens färg 
    g.setColor( color );


    g.fillOval( x, y, diameter, diameter );
}


void constrain() {
    // Ge absoluta koordinater för det rektangulära området
    int x0 = box.x;
    int y0 = box.y;
    int x1 = x0 + box.width - diameter;
    int y1 = y0 + box.height - diameter;

    // Setting speed and angels
    if (x < x0)
        dx = Math.abs(dx);
    if (x > x1)
        dx = -Math.abs(dx);
    if (y < y0)
        dy = Math.abs(dy);
    if (y > y1)
        dy = -Math.abs(dy);
}

// movingt the ball
    x = x + dx;
    y = y + dy;

    constrain();
}
```

}

I am a total rookie of java! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your Ball Class

```
private minSize = 1;
private maxSize = 10;

public void setDiameter(int newDiameter) {
  this.diameter = newDiameter;
}

public int getMinSize() {
  return minSize; 
}

public int getMinSize() {
  return maxSize; 
}
```

Use this when you use the ball

```
Ball ball = new Ball(1,1,1,1);
int newDiameter = 10;
if(newDiameter == ball.getMinSize()) {
    ball.setDiameter(ball.getMaxSize());
} 
id(newDiameter == ball.getMaxSize()) {
    ball.setDiameter (ball.getMinSize());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! I tryed your code, could not get it to work. I did what you said but the balls did not change size. Could be because newDiameter is declared as 10*2?

Comment: Wait, i used 10*2 as random number. Depends all from the value of minSize and maxSize. Try to set maxSize = 10 and minSize = 1 in the Ball class. Then after you have created the ball set int newDiameter = 10. The diameter of the ball should return to 1 because newDiameter == ball.getMaxSize();

Comment: thanks again for your time. I cant get it to work. Nothing seems to happen. Where exactly do you meen with : "Use this when you use the ball". I changed the min and max value. Big ups!

Comment: Thanks! I solved it now. I had i changeSize metod that made the diameter not change. I disabeld that. Now it works!! I wish you a nice weekend. @vaultboy

Answer (score 0):

Add the following into your Ball class:

```
private int changeFlag=-1;
```

In your constrain() function, just before the last line, after moving the ball:

```
if(diameter==maxSize) {
   changeFlag=-1;
}
else if (diameter==minSize) {
   changeFlag=1;
}

diameter=diameter+changeFlag;
```

Comment: I will allsow thank you for your fast answer! I also tryed your code, could not get it to work. Where exactly is it that you say the last bit of code should be put? "In your constrain() function, just before the last line, after moving the ball:" im not shure I know where you meen.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited it, is this what you mean?

Main Class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        // configure JFrame
        setSize(640, 360);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // create ball
        Ball ball = new Ball(this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2, 50, 100);
        add(ball);
        Thread t = new Thread(ball);
        t.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    }

}
```

Ball Class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JComponent;


public class Ball extends JComponent implements Runnable {

private int x, y, minDiameter, maxDiameter, currentDiameter, growRate = -1;
private Color color = Color.BLUE;

public Ball(int x, int y, int minDiameter, int maxDiameter) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.minDiameter = minDiameter;
    this.maxDiameter = maxDiameter;
    this.currentDiameter = minDiameter;
    setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {

        // coerce max and min size          
        if (this.currentDiameter + growRate > maxDiameter) {
            this.currentDiameter = maxDiameter;     
            this.growRate = -1;
        }
        if (this.currentDiameter + growRate < minDiameter) {
            this.currentDiameter = minDiameter; 
            this.growRate = 1;
        }

        this.currentDiameter += this.growRate;
        repaint();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON));
    g2.setColor(this.color);
    g2.fillOval(this.x, this.y, this.currentDiameter, this.currentDiameter);
}



}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not looking for the balls to change size when i click the mouse. I rater what them to change size when they reach there max or min diameter.